# run Xpath on xml stored in variable (getting "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function")

Tags: javascript, jquery, xpath

I'm trying to evaluate the XML stored in a variable using and Xpath expression, but I'm getting a console error "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/c91fja0h/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = '<books><book><title>ABC</title><author>Smith, John</author><subject>Science Fiction</subject></book><book><title>DEF</title><author>Jones, Tom</author><subject>Biography</subject></book></books>';
                var title = data.evaluate('//books/book[1]/title', data, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                alert(title);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the evaluate method is a member of the document object, so you need to call `document.evaluate(...)`

Secondly, the contextNode parameter (where you are sending in the data string) needs to be a DOM node.  An easy fix for that is to wrap the data param in a jquery object and get the DOM node from that.

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
     var data = '<books><book><title>ABC</title><author>Smith, John</author><subject>Science Fiction</subject></book><book><title>DEF</title><author>Jones, Tom</author><subject>Biography</subject></book></books>';
     var title = document.evaluate('//books/book[1]/title', $(data).get(0), null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
                alert(title);
});
```

Here's an updated fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/c91fja0h/2/

**UPDATE**

To get the actual text of the returned node, you need to change the XPathResult from ANY to ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE and then you need to access the innerText property of the returned object.

Updated code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var data = '<books><book><title>ABC</title><author>Smith, John</author><subject>Science Fiction</subject></book><book><title>DEF</title><author>Jones, Tom</author><subject>Biography</subject></book></books>';
                var title = document.evaluate('/books/book[1]/title', $(data).get(0), null, XPathResult.ANY_UNORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null);
                alert(title.singleNodeValue.innerText);
});
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c91fja0h/3/

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  Your code does eliminate the error, so far so good there.  What I am trying to do, however, is store the text() result of this Xpath query in the variable title.  It looks like I am storing an Xpath object in title right now.  How do I get the text result out of the object?

Comment: for some reason this code fails in Firefox but works in Chrome/Safari.  Any idea why?

Comment: Try using innerHTML instead of innerText.  Not sure Firefox supports innerText in this context.